# Customize the log's filename when using TimeAndSizeRollingAppender

Tags: java, log4j, logback, appender

I'm using log4j and I want 'TimeAndSizeRollingAppender' such as logback.

And I found this: http://www.simonsite.org.uk/javadoc/timeandsize/uk/org/simonsite/log4j/appender/TimeAndSizeRollingAppender.html

It said that the file name would be something like `foo.log.2007-01-01.1`, but I want it to be `foo_2007-01-01.1.log`.

Comment: formatting, removed double example

Comment: Maybe you can find your answer on this post : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13936021/rolling-logs-by-size-and-time